# Get Value of a Div that Has No ID Using Javascript (Only has a Class)

Tags: javascript, element

I'm trying to get the value of a div using javascript.  This particular div element has no ID, it only has a class.  The HTML looks like this:

```
Some text I don't care about
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="class_I_dont_care_about">
    <div class="need_value_from_this_div">
        Value I Need to Get Using Javascript
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I forgot to specify that "getbyelementclass" is not an option, as it is only supported by IE 9, & the latest versions of chrome, FF & opera, so I'm looking for a more "mult-browser" option, if at all possible.

Comment: Depending on the browsers you need to support, you can use [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName)

Comment: Thank you for bringing that up vcsjones, I forgot to specify that is not an option.  I edited my original question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

```
var value = document.getElementsByClassName('need_value_from_this_div')[0].innerHTML;
```

Comment: Thank you very much leonw, while this is a valid answer to my "before edit" question, I'm an idiot and forgot to specify I need something that is a little more "cross browser compatible".  I edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: No problem, in that case I think the easiest solution is to select the wrapper. Then use methods like .childNodes to climb down the DOM-tree and select the desired <div> tag. I think this is cross-browser. But I haven't checked it, sorry if I'm wrong !

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelectorAll()`

```
  var elem = document.querySelectorAll( '.' + class);
    var text = elem[0].innerHTML
```

It should work even with **IE-8**

Otherwise the better option will be `.getElementsByClassName()`

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/nkqC7/1/)**

```
var className = 'a';
var elems = getByClass(className);

for(var i =0;i<elems.length;i++){
    console.log(elems[i].innerHTML);
}

function getByClass(className){
    var elems = [];
    if(document.querySelectorAll){
        elems = document.querySelectorAll( '.' + className);
    }
    else{
        elems = document.getElementsByClassName( '.' + className);
    }       
    return elems;    
}
```